# How to create RSA key with custom exponent size

Tags: c#, rsa

I need to create RSA key pair with custom public exponent size (specifically 64 bytes). Creating like this:

```
var rsa = new RSACng();
PrivateKey = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
```

or this

```
var rsa = RSA.Create();
PrivateKey = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
```

Always results in 3-bytes exponent: 1,0,1.

I've seen people are writing, that `RSACng` should support custom size exponent, but I can not find any good example.

Comment: I know that the Microsoft CSP's were always limited to 32 bit exponents, and all default key pair generation functions seem to use F4, the fifth prime or Fermat that you mention (things may have changed in the mean time though). Maybe try Bouncy Castle for C#?

Comment: I assume Bouncy Castle can not be run on linux, because i requires .Net Framework not Core. There is Bouncy Castle Core, but I don't know how to implement this code with that library.

Comment: Ugh, I always forget the terrible source code quality of BC, but you can see the generation class [here](https://github.com/chrishaly/bc-csharp/blob/master/crypto/src/crypto/generators/RsaKeyPairGenerator.cs), which includes setting the public exponent. Note that I would not recommend using the class in an insecure location due to side channel attack possibilities on prime number generation.

Comment: [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4cLnEH) is an example code (executable online) how to create a key with user defined exponent using C#/.NET5/BC.NetCore. Maybe you can port this to your environment. Regardless of the porting aspect, the BC library requires the use of [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) for the exponent. I.e. you will not be able to apply a 64 bytes exponent, the closest Fermat number is F9 with 65 bytes (2^(2^9) + 1).